# Compilando com g++

Tags: c++, compilação, gcc

Estou compilando um código de exemplo fornecido no site da livraria GLFW da seguinte maneira: `g++ main.cpp -o main.exe glfw3dll.a` <- desta maneira é possível compilar, mas e se eu quiser mudar os arquivos de lugar?

Minha intenção é manter uma estrutura

```
+include
--GLFW/glfw3.h
+libs
--glfw3dll.a
```

Porém não consigo linkar a livraria com o comando `-L/libs/ -lglfw3dll`

```
g++ main.cpp -o main.exe -L/libs/ -lglfw3dll

ld.exe: cannot find -lglfw3dll
collect.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Como o compilador não encontra a livraria se eu estou informando no comando onde ela está?

Comment: A livraria que você especificou é uma static linked library, não é? Pelo que eu sei, esse processo de linkagem dinâmica só funciona com bibliotecas de link dinâmico (terminam com .so). Recompile o seu glfw3.h como uma biblioteca de link dinâmico e tente fazer isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não consegue linkar utilizando a flag `-l` pois o nome da biblioteca devia ser `libglfw3dll.a`.

Pois como ja mencionei num dos meus posts antigos é obrigatório ter `lib` no nome.

Comment: Pô, cara, não sei com que cara eu fico, eu reparei que conseguia linkar as outras bibliotecas que tinham lib no prefixo, mas estava com tanto sono que nem tentei alterar o nome da que eu precisava linkar. Obrigado!